# MicroPython can't find module in lib folder on a Pico

Tags: import, module, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

In an attempt to find a minimal reproducible example for a bigger problem, I have a Raspberry Pi Pico using micropython.

On the Pico's file system, I have the following folder structure:

```
/lib
    /test_mod
        test_mod.py
```

test_mod.py consists of just the following function.

```
def do_stuff():
    print("hello")
```

I'm using Thonny, and when I try and run this program.

```
import test_mod

test_mod.do_stuff()
```

I get the following error:

```
>>> %Run -c $EDITOR_CONTENT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'do_stuff'
>>>
```

I have tried changing `import test_mod` to `import lib.test_mod` and even  `import lib.test_mod.test_mod`

but none work.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong import path. If your file is:

```
lib/
  test_mod/
    test_mod.py
```

Then you need:

```
import test_mod.test_mod

test_mod.test_mod.do_stuff()
```

Or:

```
import test_mod.test_mod as test_mod

test_mod.do_stuff()
```

Or:

```
from test_mod import test_mod

test_mod.do_stuff()
```

(This all assumes that your micropython `sys.path` includes `/lib`, which it should by default.)